# Are you lost yet?

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, number-theory

Your task is to implement integer sequence [A130826](https://oeis.org/A130826):

> **a<sub>n</sub>** is the smallest positive integer such that **a<sub>n</sub> - n** is an entire multiple of **3** and twice the number of divisors of **(a<sub>n</sub> - n) / 3** gives the **n**<sup>th</sup> term in the first differences of the sequence produced by the Flavius Josephus sieve.

Lost yet? Well, it's actually quite easy.

The [Flavius Josephus sieve](https://oeis.org/A000960) defines an integer sequence as follows.

1. Start with the sequence of positive integers and set **k = 2**.
2. Remove every **k**<sup>th</sup> integer of the sequence, starting with the **k**<sup>th</sup>.
3. Increment **k** and go back to step 2.

**f<sub>n</sub>** is the **n**<sup>th</sup> integer (1-indexed) that never gets removed.

If – as usual – **σ<sub>0</sub>(k)** denotes the number of positive divisors of the integer **k**, we can define **a<sub>n</sub>** as the smallest positive integer such that **2σ<sub>0</sub>((a<sub>n</sub> - n) / 3) = f<sub>n+1</sub> - f<sub>n</sub>**.

#### Challenge

Write a program or function that takes a positive integer **n** as input and prints or returns **a<sub>n</sub>**.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. May the shortest code win!

#### Worked examples

If we remove every second element of the positive integers, we are left with

```
 1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39 ...
```

After removing every third element of the remainder, we get

```
 1  3  7  9 13 15 19 21 25 27 31 33 37 39 ...
```

Now, removing every fourth, then fifth, then sixth element gets us

```
 1  3  7 13 15 19 25 27 31 37 39 ...
 1  3  7 13 19 25 27 31 39 ...
 1  3  7 13 19 27 31 39 ...
 1  3  7 13 19 27 39 ...
```

The last row shows the terms **f<sub>1</sub>** to **f<sub>7</sub>**.

The differences of the consecutive elements of the these terms are

```
 2  4  6  6  8 12
```

Dividing these forward differences by **2**, we get

```
 1  2  3  3  4  6
```

These are the target divisor counts.

- **4** is the first integer **k** such that **σ<sub>0</sub>((k - 1) / 3) = 1**. In fact, **σ<sub>0</sub>(1) = 1**.
- **8** is the first integer **k** such that **σ<sub>0</sub>((k - 2) / 3) = 2**. In fact, **σ<sub>0</sub>(2) = 2**.
- **15** is the first integer **k** such that **σ<sub>0</sub>((k - 3) / 3) = 3**. In fact, **σ<sub>0</sub>(4) = 3**.
- **16** is the first integer **k** such that **σ<sub>0</sub>((k - 4) / 3) = 3**. In fact, **σ<sub>0</sub>(4) = 3**.
- **23** is the first integer **k** such that **σ<sub>0</sub>((k - 5) / 3) = 4**. In fact, **σ<sub>0</sub>(6) = 4**.
- **42** is the first integer **k** such that **σ<sub>0</sub>((k - 6) / 3) = 6**. In fact, **σ<sub>0</sub>(12) = 6**.

#### Test cases

```
   n     a(n)

   1        4
   2        8
   3       15
   4       16
   5       23
   6       42
   7       55
   8      200
   9       81
  10       46
  11      119
  12      192
  13      205
  14   196622
  15    12303
  16       88
  17      449
  18      558
  19      127
  20     1748
  21   786453
  22       58
  23     2183
  24     3096
  25     1105
  26   786458
  27 12582939
  28      568
  29     2189
  30     2730
```

Comment: Keyword on OEIS: __dumb__ ("an unimportant sequence").

Comment: Dumb? It could save the world!

Comment: That pun though...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Jelly, <s>30</s> <s>29</s> <s>27</s> 25 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Dennis notifying me about `Æd`, and another 2 bytes for combining the two chains.*

```
RUð÷‘Ċ×µ/
‘Ç_ÇH0Æd=¥1#×3+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@x8UenjD4e2PGmYc6To8/dBWfS4g83B7/OF2D4PDbSm2h5YaKh@ebqz9//9/MwA)

This was probably the most fun I've ever had with Jelly. I started from the second line, which calculates **f<sub>n</sub>** from **n** using the formula on OEIS, and is quite beautiful.

#### Explanation

```
RUð÷‘Ċ×µ/    Helper link to calculate Fn. Argument: n
R            Get numbers [1..n]
 U           Reverse
        /    Reduce by "round up to next 2 multiples":
   ÷           Divide by the next number
    ‘          Increment to skip a multiple
     Ċ         Ceil (round up)
      ×        Multiply by the next number

‘Ç_ÇH0Æd=¥1#×3+    Main link. Argument: n
‘                  Increment n
 Ç                 Calculate Fn+1
   Ç               Calculate Fn
  _                Subtract
    H              Divide by 2
     0    1#       Starting from 0, find the first candidate for (an-n)/3
                   that satisfies...
      Æd             σ0((an-n)/3)
        =            = (Fn+1-Fn)/2
            ×3     Multiply by 3 to turn (an-n)/3 into an-n
              +    Add n to turn an-n into an
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>121</s> <s>119</s> 118 bytes

```python
n=input();r=range(1,4**n);d=s,=r*1,
for k in r:del s[k::k+1];d+=sum(k%j<1for j in r)*2,
print d.index(s[n]-s[n-1])*3+n
```

Run time should be roughly **O(16<sup>n</sup>)** with **O(4<sup>n</sup>)** memory usage. Replacing `4**n` with `5<<n` – which I *think* is sufficient – would improve this dramatically, but I'm not convinced that it works for arbitrarily large values of **n**.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#HcpLCsIwEADQfU8xGyG/ClFxkTgnKVkIEyWNjmXSgrePn81bvc5YeNlWpaOgXPmelXcnY1hHwuZQjHfD7SVQoTBIoPyANtUQqvUpksW2PVXdzRf/S/M/aXNwwyKFV6B9Ycpv1SZO45fRJ22Olns/fwA)

#### Asymptotic behavior and upper bounds of a<sub>n</sub>

Define **b<sub>n</sub>** as **(a<sub>n</sub> - n)/3**, i.e., the smallest positive integer **k** such that **σ<sub>0</sub>(k) = ½(f<sub>n+1</sub> - f<sub>n</sub>)**.

As noted on the OEIS page, **f<sub>n</sub> ~ ¼πn<sup>2</sup>**, so **f<sub>n+1</sub> - f<sub>n</sub> ~ ¼π(n + 1)<sup>2</sup> - ¼πn<sup>2</sup> = ¼π(2n + 1) ~ ½πn**.

This way, **½(f<sub>n+1</sub> - f<sub>n</sub>) ~ ¼πn**. If the actual number is a prime **p**, the smallest positive integer with **p** divisors is **2<sup>p-1</sup>**, so **b<sub>n</sub>** can be approximated by **2<sup>c<sub>n</sub></sup>**, where **c<sub>n</sub> ~ ¼πn**.

Therefore **b<sub>n</sub> < 4<sup>n</sup>** will hold for sufficiently large **n**, and given that **2<sup>¼πn</sup> < 2<sup>n</sup> << (2<sup>n</sup>)<sup>2</sup> = 4<sup>n</sup>**, I'm confident there are no counterexamples.

#### How it works

```python
n=input();r=range(1,4**n);d=s,=r*1,
```

This sets up a few references for our iterative process.

- **n** is the user input: a positive integer.
- **r** is the list **[1, ..., 4<sup>n</sup> - 1]**.
- **s** is a copy of **r**.

  Repeating the list once with `r*1` creates a shallow copy, so modifying **s** won't modify **r**.
- **d** is initialized as the tuple **(s)**.

  This first value is not important. All others will hold divisor counts of positive integers.

```python
for k in r:del s[k::k+1];d+=sum(k%j<1for j in r)*2,
```

For each integer **k** from **1** to **4<sup>n</sup> - 1**, we do the following.

- `del s[k::k+1]` takes every **(k + 1)**<sup>th</sup> integer in **s** – starting with the **(k + 1)**<sup>th</sup> – and deletes that slice from **s**.

  This is a straightforward way of storing an initial interval of the Flavius Josephus sieve in **s**. It will compute much more than the required **n + 1** initial terms, but using a single `for` loop to update both **s** and **d** saves some bytes.
- `d+=sum(k%j<1for j in r)*2,` counts how many elements of **r** divide **k** evenly and appends **2σ<sub>0</sub>(k)** to **d**.

  Since **d** was initialized as a singleton tuple, **2σ<sub>0</sub>(k)** is stored at index **k**.

```python
print d.index(s[n]-s[n-1])*3+n
```

This finds the first index of **f<sub>n+1</sub> - f<sub>n</sub>** in **d**, which is the smallest **k** such that **2σ<sub>0</sub>(k) = f<sub>n+1</sub> - f<sub>n</sub>**, then computes **a<sub>n</sub>** as **3k + 1** and prints the result.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8,  <strike>336</strike>, <strike>305</strike>, <strike>303</strike>, <strike>287</strike>, <strike>283</strike> 279 bytes

57 bytes removed thanks to Kritixi Lithos

Golfed

```java
class f{static int g(int s,int N){return s<1?N+1:g(s-1,N+N/s);}static int h(int k){int u=0,t=1,i;for(;u!=(g(k,k)-g(k,k-1))/2;t++)for(i=1,u=0;i<=t;)if(t%i++<1)u++;return 3*t-3+k;}public static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(h(new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextInt()));}}
```

Ungolfed

```java
class f {
    static int g(int s,int N){return s < 1 ? N + 1 : g(s - 1, N + N / s);}

    static int h(int k) {
        int u = 0, t = 1, i;
        // get the first number with v divisors
        while(u != (g(k, k) - g(k, k - 1))/2){
            u = 0;
            for (i = 1; i <= t; i++)
                if (t % i < 1) u++;
            t++;
        }
        // 3*(t-1)+k = 3*t+k-3
        return 3 * t + k - 3;
    }

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        System.out.print(h(new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextInt()));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think parsing the command-line arguments as an `int` is shorter than using `java.util.Scanner`. But even if you're using Scanner, you can do `System.out.print(h(new java.util.Scanner().nextInt()))` and remove the previous line

Comment: @KritixiLithos thx, fixing now...

Comment: Inside `int h()`, you can change it to `int v = (g(k,k)-g(k,k-1))/2,u = 0,t = 1;`. You can change your if-statement (that is inside your for-loop) from `if(t%i==0)` to `if(t%i<1)`

Comment: Additionally, you can change your function `g` to return using ternary operators something like `return s==0?N+1:g(s-1,N+N/2)`-ish

Comment: Also inside function `h` you can do `int v = (g(k,k)-g(k,k-1))/2,u=0,t=1,i` (notice the `i`) so that inside your for-loop you can have `for(i=1` instead by dropping the `int` and saving bytes

Comment: @KritixiLithos sorry didn't see comments earlier i just added in your last edit

Comment: Also [this saves bytes](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/104389/are-you-lost-yet/104757?noredirect=1#comment254517_104757) :)

Comment: @KritixiLithos i pasted it in and it was returning `1 -> 1`,`2 -> 5`, `3 -> 6` instead of `1 -> 4`,`2 -> 8`,`3 -> 15` sorry for my incompetence and again thx for the help

Comment: It works for me though

Comment: @KritixiLithos this is what i used: `static int g(int s,int N){return s==0?N+1:g(s-1,N+N/2);}`

Comment: It works for me on TIO: https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#TU@xboMwFPwVd6jkVxsSN1sdq3MXFsaqg0sNvEJMhJ9JK8S3UxMxdHh30ulO726tehsCq@dAlrBi6Ik1fMMgNyxgHh3F0bNgzPG1EOql4SFTshDFIYBe/uXae66DeaPJ8IZ3soPsTpkCODzLaI6SjJKoby32jscHM8GcVF0PI0ejNJ4NaRQCsOb0iGcFUQhN6Za9yOmJspPo9HKNn316vTeYBvxiF4uelzSib94/LMzlbyB3yYdI@TWJxFvu3Y1928nmkbDPy8p670a@G9FD7t0PvSUrQJq3rKv6Aw

Comment: alright changing...

Comment: You can shorten it by removing `i++` from the for-loop and by changing the if-statement under it to `if(t%i++<1)` https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#TU@7boQwEPwVp4jkjQ2HQxeflToNDWWUwiE8NnDmhNdcIsS3E3OiSLEz0mhGO7NVg/WeNYsnS1gxdMRavqOXOxawTDWFyTFvTPZaCPXScp8oWYji5EGv/3LdPdfDstNseMt72UNyp0QBnJ5lMJkkoyTqW4dDzcODmWGJqm7GiaNRGs@GNGDD6RGFOCsIQmiKtx498idKctHr9Ro@h/j5KDCP@MUuFh0vaULXvn9YWMpfT/UlHQOl1ygS77irb@zbzjYNhENaVta5euKHER2krv6ht2gFiOvWbcuzPw

Comment: You can remove `v=g(...` and instead have `while(u!=(g(k,k)-g(k,k-1))/2)` https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#TY8xb4MwEIX/ijtU8tWGxMkWx@rchYWx6uBSA1eIifA5aYX47dREDB3uPen0Pb27peptCKyeAlnCiqEn1vBVg1y1gGl0FEfPgjH710KoU8NDpmQhil0APf/LtY9cB9Nq0ewlGSVR31vsHY9Phje8kx1kD8sUwO4AU@J0PYwcjdJ4NqQBa07PKMRZQRRCU5p5u@H4QtlRdHq@xs8@tW7ltwG/2MWi5yWN6Jv3DwtT@RvIXfIhUn5NS@It9@7Ovu3N5pGwz8vKeu9GvoHoIffuh94SCpA@m5fl8Ac

Comment: In `int g()` I modified the return statement so that I used `s<1` instead. Also in `int h()` I changed the `while` loop to a `for` loop and moved things around so that it would be shorter: https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#TY@xboQwEER/xSkieWPjO4fuDEqdhoYySuEQ4DZw5mSvL4kQ307MiSLNjLQ7T6NZm9GGwLo5kCVsGDpiPd80yE0rmH1L0TsWCv1SCX3qeci0rER1CGCWf9j5jg0wbxbLo6RSSzTd5LmJDyXv@SAHyO6WaYDDsyEhYPtjSibCYFGSAew4PaIQhYYohNn78yfKcjGY5Ro/xlS5N98m/GQXi47X5NH1b@8W5vo3UHtRUyR1TUfiZ@7ab/Zlb1ZFwlHVjXWu9XwPogPl2h96TVGANGtZ1/z4Bw

Comment: @KritixiLithos lol at this point u should just post this as ur own separate solution

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>130</s> <s>116</s> <s>106</s> 103 bytes

```
3Catch@Do[f=#2⌈#/#2+1⌉&~Fold~Reverse@Range@#&;If[Tr[2+0Divisors@k]==f[#+1]-f@#,Throw@k],{k,∞}]+#&
```

or

```
3Catch@Do[f=#2⌈#/#2+1⌉&~Fold~Reverse@Range@#&;If[2DivisorSum[k,1&]==f[#+1]-f@#,Throw@k],{k,∞}]+#&
```

Ended up being almost identical to @Pietu1998's Jelly code...

**Explanation**

```
Catch@
```

`Catch` whatever is `Throw`-ed (thrown).

```
Do[ ... ,{k,∞}]
```

Infinite loop; `k` starts from `1` and increments every iteration.

```
f= ...
```

Assign `f`:

```
Reverse@Range@#
```

Find `{1, 2, ... , n}`. Reverse it.

```
#2⌈#/#2+1⌉&
```

A function that outputs ceil(n1/n2 + 1) * n2

```
f= ... ~Fold~ ... &
```

Assign `f` a function that recursively applies the above function to the list from two steps above, using each output as the first input and each element of the list as the second input. The initial "output" (first input) is the first element of the list.

```
Tr[2+0Divisors@k]==f[#+1]-f@#
```

Check whether twice the number of divisors of `k` is equal to f(n + 1) - f(n).

```
If[ ... ,Throw@k]
```

If the condition is `True`, `Throw` the value of `k`. If not, continue looping.

```
3 ... +#&
```

Multiply the output by 3 and add n.

**130 byte version**

```
Catch@Do[s=#+1;a=k-#;If[3∣a&&2DivisorSigma[0,a/3]==Differences[Nest[i=1;Drop[#,++i;;;;i]&,Range[s^2],s]][[#]],Throw@k],{k,∞}]&
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <del>35</del> <del>34</del> 39 bytes

```
1Qi4ë[N3*¹+NÑg·¹D>‚vyy<LRvy/>îy*}}‚Æ(Q#
```

It looks awful, so is runtime performance. It takes several seconds for input that yield small values. Don't try numbers like 14; it will eventually find the result but it would take ages.

### Explanation

It works as 2 sequentially called programs. The first one computes **F<sub>n+1</sub> - F<sub>n</sub>** and the second one determines **a<sub>n</sub>** based on its definition, using a bruteforce approach.

**F<sub>n+1</sub> - F<sub>n</sub>** is evaluated for each iteration even though it is loop invariant. It makes the code time inefficient, but it makes the code shorter.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#ATMAzP//xb5ITMK5wrXCvERnTMK@PiUww4rDj33CpcK5PMOoVVtOMyrCuStOw5FnwrdYUSP//zg)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why can't it compute the sieve above 65,536?

Comment: It comes from the fact that it generates all integers between 0 and 65536 (`žHL`) and then filters out the values that don't satisfy the sieve constraints. I think the first part of this program should be entirely rewritten with a completely different approach to make it golfable.

Comment: Unless there are limitations (like fixed width integers) that prevent you from doing so, answers are expected to work for any input, given enough time and memory.

Comment: That's why I came up with another sieve algorithm. It might be golfable but I haven't found better in 05AB1E. However there is a counterexample to `given enough time and memory`, since I already saw several answers on other questions that ran so slowly that it was nearly impossible to say whether they produced the right output or not. For this reason I put the sieve computation aside from the loop and it cost me 2 bytes.

Comment: No need to make your code efficient. You can make the golfed/slow implementation your submission and include the faster/longer one as a side note. I'm afraid I have to insist on the dynamic limit though, even if it costs a byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), <s>154</s> <s>149</s> <s>136</s> 107 bytes

```
->\n{n+3*first ->\o{([-] ->\m{m??&?BLOCK(m-1).rotor(m+0=>1).flat!!1..*}(n)[n,n-1])/2==grep o%%*,1..o},^Inf}
```

Ungolfed:

```
-> \n {                    # Anonymous sub taking argument n
  n + 3 * first -> \o {    # n plus thrice the first integer satisfying:
    (                      #
      [-]                  #
      -> \m {              # Compute nth sieve iteration:
        m                  # If m is nonzero,
          ?? &?BLOCK(m-1).rotor(m+0=>1).flat # then recurse and remove every (m+1)-th element;
          !! 1..*          # the base case is all of the positive integers
      }                    #
      (n)                  # Get the nth sieve
      [n,n-1]              # Get the difference between the nth and (n-1)th elements (via the [-] reduction operator above)
    ) / 2                  # and divide by 2;
    ==                     # We want the number that equals
    grep o %% *, 1..o      # the number of divisors of o.
  }
  ,^Inf
}
```